# Please check my SQL query that may lead to performance issue on huge database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-performance

I have two tables:

Customer table:

- id (Primary Key)
- email_id
- role_id
- individual_id (Foreign key).

Individual table:

- individual_id
- dob

I want to find all duplicate records whose `email_id`, `role_id` and `dob`are same.

I have created a query using simple join and group by clause as below:

```
SELECT c.email_id, c.role_id, i.dob 
FROM CUSTOMER c   
JOIN INDIVIDUAL i on c.individual_id = i.individual_id
GROUP BY c.email_id, c.role_id, i.dob
Having count(*) >= 2
```

It is working fine on test database (SQL Server 2012), but I would like to know that does my query would have performance issue on production database(around 5 million) or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your query is missing its `GROUP BY` clause.  I can't suggest a better query, but I can suggest that you include indices on the join columns.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thanks i was a typo mistake.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Performance issues are often product specific.

Comment: I'm using MSSQL 2012 database.

Answer (score 0):

performance issue is based on your DB size and live changes of data into db.

```
            set statistics time on   -- show  you exec time

            SELECT top 10 c.email_id,c.role_id,i.dob 
            FROM CUSTOMER c   (nolock)
            JOIN INDIVIDUAL  i (nolock) on c.individual_id=i.individual_id
            GROUP BY c.email_id,c.role_id,i.dob 
            Having count(*) >=2
```

use NOLOCK it can prevent reads being deadlocked by other operations,

First try top 10 query to see execution time. then you can try it for more rows.

or also you can impoert data temp table then you can find duplicate data.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. Which dbms this for?

Comment: is it for sql server.

Comment: Keep in mind that using `NOLOCK` could result in dirty reads. It all depends on what the user intends to do with his result to determine if this is an option or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH numbered 
     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
                  OVER(PARTITION BY c.email_id, c.role_id, i.dob 
                       ORDER BY c.email_id, c.role_id, i.dob) AS _dupe_num, 
                c.email_id, 
                c.role_id, 
                i.dob 
         FROM   customer c 
                INNER JOIN individual i 
                        ON c.individual_id = i.individual_id) 

SELECT c.email_id, c.role_id, i.dob -- You can add a DISTINCT or GROUP here if required.
FROM   numbered 
WHERE  _dupe_num > 1;
```

This is another approach to the same problem. You can compare execution plans. I however *don't see any real issue with the query you posted*.

Have you considered loading up your test environment with over 5M records for those tables? Generating those should be fairly easy. If you need some test values you can always grab and concat some stuff from AdventureWorks.